# Expansion of polynomial raised to high power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is there an easy way to expand something like (x + x^2 + x^3)^6 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: study binomial theorem !

Comment: As far as I know binomial theorem only works with, well, expanding binomials. I know there's something similar for trinomials but it involves finding all the possible combinations for a specific term, which gets a bit tricky. I was wondering if there's a systematic way of getting that part.

Comment: There usually isn't an "easy way" of doing anything; we're very lucky if we can find something for the general case (see: the irreducibility of quintic polynomials over the radicals, hence a quintic formula doesn't exist).
But there is a formula that's a natural extension of the binomial one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

My approach avoids multinomials:

Let's play with it a bit:
$$\begin{align}
(x+x^2+x^3)^6 &= x^6(1+x+x^2)^6\\
&= x^6\frac{((1-x)(1+x+x^2))^6}{(1-x)^6}\\
&= \frac{x^6(1-x^3)^6}{(1-x)^6} \\
\end{align}$$
The numerator and denominator can now be expanded with the binomial theorem, and then long division will simplify the expression. (This is the way I would do it.)

Another approach: 
$$\begin{align}
(x+x^2+x^3)^6 &= (x+(x^2+x^3))^6 \\
&= x^6+6x^5(x^2+x^3) + 15x^4(x^2+x^3)^2 \\
& +\, 20x^3(x^2+x^3)^3 + 15x^2(x^2+x^3)^4 + 6x(x^2+x^3)^5 + (x^2+x^3)^6
\end{align}$$

Now, each of the binomials can be expanded as above.

Comment: Or expand $(1-x)^{-6}$ by the Binomial Theorem. Although that gives an infinite series, which is a bit unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very compact solution for expanding an all-ones polynomial with no constant term presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302298/formula-for-coefficients-of-an-exponentiation-of-all-one-polynomial), demonstrated with SymPy/Python below:

```
>>> from sympy import binomial
>>> Limits = lambda i,j: range(i,j+1)  # to give values i-j
>>> list(Limits(1,3))
>>> [1, 2, 3]

>>> k=3  # for x + x**2 + x**3
>>> n=6
>>> [sum((-1)**i*binomial(n,i)*binomial(r-i*k-1,n-1)
...  for i in Limits(0,(r-n)//k)) for r in Limits(n,k*n)]
[1, 6, 21, 50, 90, 126, 141, 126, 90, 50, 21, 6, 1]
```

In your case having row 6 and diagonal 5 (down through row 13) of Pascal's triangle will help with the binomials.