# Formula for coefficients of an exponentiation of all one polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

I am solving a following problem.

Let's have $(x^1+\ldots+x^k)^n$, then find a formula for coefficients $a_r$. ($a_r$ is a coefficient at $x^r$.)

I used the formula for geometric series to get $x^n\left(\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\right)^n$. Then using the generalized binomial theorem I got $x^n\cdot\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+i-1}{n-1}x^i\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-x)^{ik}\right)$. From this, I managed to extract a formula for $a_r$ in a form

$a_r=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{r-n}{k}\rfloor}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{r-ik-1}{n-1}$

Does there exist a shorter formula? E.g. without summation or with fewer terms.

Comment: maybe you meant $(x^1+...+x^k)^n$ rather then $(x_1+...+x_k)^n$?

Comment: There does not exist a shorter formula (the formula is well known, and is always stated as the one you wrote).

Comment: And don't forget the symmetry of the problem which makes $a_{n + j}$ and $a_{nk-j}$ for $n+j \le nk-j$, so we never run the summation higher than for $r = \lceil nk/2 \rceil$.

Comment: See also [the use of a generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/371914/122921) to get the coefficient for arbitrary $n$.